# How to Differentiate Microsoft MSA and AAD accounts

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory

We have created converged application to which AAD and Live users can login. We want to know logged in user having Live or AAD account.

Is there any API or value from IdToken/Graph API that we can use to differentiate MSA or AAD.

Answer (score 3):

The Id token you receive after login contains the tenant ID in the `tid` claim.

For example:

```
b9419818-09af-49c2-b0c3-653adc1f376e
```

The GUID is the id for the tenant. In case of MSA, this value will be:

```
9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad
```

Source: [Azure Active Directory v2.0 tokens reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens)

> A GUID that represents the Azure AD tenant that the user is from. For work and school accounts, the GUID is the immutable tenant ID of the organization that the user belongs to. For personal accounts, the value is 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad. The profile scope is required in order to receive this claim.

You can also get this id from the `iss` claim, which is the issuer.

Comment: There is also `idp` claim `id_token`.It records the identity provider that authenticated the subject of the token.  I think it may be better to used to differentiate the IDP of the account.

Comment: Is that also in v2 endpoint Id tokens? If it is, it is not documented :D

Comment: I test again and foud the `idp` claim is also in access token.

Comment: FWIW in 2024 I'm not seeing `idp` in v2 tokens